# OAuth and obtaining shared secret securely

Tags: security, oauth

I am building a downloadable web application, which is packaged as a ZIP archive. When downloaded webmaster is taken through installer. As one step of the installer, he is asked to "register" his copy from the main site. After registration is successful I need to issue that particular copy of my software a shared key/secret for further API access through OAuth.

Please advise the most secure and correct way to do this. Again, here are steps:

- software is downloaded (same zip for everyone, cannot contain secrets)
- webmaster opens wizard (by pointing his browser at localhost)
- wizard redirect to example.com where user enters his credential
- user is then sent back to localhost along with

  - oauth key
  - shared secret
- in the future software can access API directly through OAuth token.

Another question is can I obtain token during the initial handshake or should I perform that step later.

Answer (score 1):

Have the web app itself perform the transaction itself, and then collect the secret directly. Don't have the users go to the external site.

[image: Secret Sequence Diagram]

Comment: then attackers can use the "reg info" sending to do all sorts of nasty things.